# SQL-use FOR XML PATH for two TABLE

Tags: sql-server

I have two TABLE (SQL Server 2016)

```
--TABLE
CREATE TABLE TEST (
Num VARCHAR(50),
OID VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES ('1', 'Lisa'),
('2', 'Fanny'),
('3', 'Doris'),
('4', 'Tom'),
('5', 'Johnson'),
('6', 'Seam'),
('7', 'Matt');

CREATE TABLE TEST2 (
Num VARCHAR(50),
OID VARCHAR(50),
TAB2C VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO TEST2
VALUES ('1', 'Fanny','A'),
('2', 'Johnson','B'),
('3', 'Seam','C');
```

Usually I only use FOR XML PATH for the second TABLE

```
SELECT  ',' + TAB2C
FROM TEST2
FOR XML PATH('')

output:
,A,B,C
```

Now I need to connect with the first TABLE

I can't get the result I want

```
SELECT  ',' +  T2.TAB2C
FROM TEST2 T2
left join TEST1 T1 on T1.OID= T2.OID
FOR XML PATH('')

output:
,A,B,C

hope output:
0,A,0,0,B,C,0
```

Hope to use OID to judge, if no data is found, add 0

Or is there any way I can do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LEFT JOIN` is the wrong way round. It also references an invalid object (it's `TEST` not `TEST1`). Finally, you need to wrap `T2.TAB2C` in an `ISNULL`. I also add in a `STUFF` to remove the first delimiter:

```sql
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + ISNULL(T2.TAB2C,0)
              FROM dbo.TEST T
                   LEFT JOIN dbo.TEST2 T2 ON T.OID= T2.OID
              ORDER BY T.Num
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=862ea0a32255672bbdad91add1087c49)

Comment: `TAB2C` is `varchar` is it not? Do you not want to prevent implicit conversion problems?

Comment: What is your point, @Charlieface ? I didn't say it wasn't.

Comment: What implicit conversion problem, @Charlieface ? `0` can be converted to a `varchar` just fine.

Comment: `0` to `varchar`, I suppose I just mean why would you put it as an `int` if it's not supposed to be one, why rely on conversion?

Comment: SQL Server has no issues converting the `int` value `0` to a `varchar`, @Charlieface . I don't understand your point here.